# Pagination on DynamoDB scan result using PHP

Tags: php, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

this is my original php script to scan the result:

```
$defaultQuery = date('Y-m-d');
$guardTimeIndex = 'guard_name-time_stamp-index';
$query = $defaultQuery;

$paramsDefaultQuery = [
  'TableName' => 'GPS-dynamoDB',
  'IndexName' => $guardTimeIndex
  'FilterExpression' => 'contains(time_stamp, :query)',
  'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
    ':query' => ['S' => $query]
   ]
];

$resultsDefaultQuery = $dynamoDb->scan($paramsDefaultQuery);
```

and this is my html tbody for displaying the result:

```
<tbody>
 <?php
 $combinedResults = $resultsDefaultQuery['Items'];

 foreach ($combinedResults as $item) :
  $timestamp = $item['time_stamp']['S'];
  $formattedTimestamp = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($timestamp));
 ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $item['checkpoint_location']['S']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $item['guard_name']['S']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $formattedTimestamp; ?></td>
  </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

the problem is I can't figure out how to make the result paginated like i used to do with relational database. i tried to use `ExclusiveStartKey` and `LastEvaluatedKey` but no success.

i tried to use the `ExclusiveStartKey` and `LastEvaluatedKey` like this:

```
$defaultQuery = date('Y-m-d');
$guardTimeIndex = 'guard_name-time_stamp-index';
$query = $defaultQuery;

$paramsDefaultQuery = [
  'TableName' => 'GPS-dynamoDB',
  'IndexName' => $guardTimeIndex
  'FilterExpression' => 'contains(time_stamp, :query)',
  'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
    ':query' => ['S' => $query]
   ]
];

$itemsPerPage = 10;
$currentpage = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $itemsPerPage;
$paramsDefaultQuery['Limit'] = $itemsPerPage;

if (isset($resultsDefaultQuery['LastEvaluatedKey']) && is_array($resultsDefaultQuery['LastEvaluatedKey']) && !empty($resultsDefaultQuery['LastEvaluatedKey'])) {
    $paramsDefaultQuery['ExclusiveStartKey'] = $resultsDefaultQuery['LastEvaluatedKey'];
} else {
    unset($paramsDefaultQuery['ExclusiveStartKey']);
}

$resultsDefaultQuery = $dynamoDb->scan($paramsDefaultQuery);

$totalItems = count($resultsDefaultQuery['Items']);
$totalPages = ceil($totalItems / $itemsPerPage);
```

but it returned no result at all on my table.

Comment: What is the result of `$resultsDefaultQuery['LastEvaluatedKey']` after you run your first query? Can you `var_dump` the result and let us know how it looked like?